# Application not started by tapping on widget

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget

Hi i am using a widget for my app with a simple text on it but when i am tapping on my widget my application is not launched.

Here's the data

WidgetProvider.java

```
public class StockWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    for (int widgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget_layout);
        // Register an onClickListener
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, StockActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                0, intent, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget, pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
    }

}
}
```

widget_provider_info.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minHeight="50dp"
android:minWidth="150dp"
android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
android:widgetCategory="home_screen"
android:previewImage="@drawable/widget_image">

</appwidget-provider>
```

widget_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/widget"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="8dp"
android:background="@drawable/widget_shape" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/update"
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:layout_margin="4dip"
    android:text="Static Text" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.stockhawk">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.StockActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".service.StockService"
        android:exported="false" />

    <service android:name=".service.DetailService"
        android:exported="false"/>

    <provider
        android:name=".data.StockProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.android.stockhawk.data.StockProvider"
        android:exported="false" />

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.DetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_detail"
        android:parentActivityName=".ui.StockActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.android.stockhawk.ui.StockActivity" />
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".service.DetailService"
        android:exported="false"/>

    <receiver android:name=".extras.StockWidgetProvider"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_provider_info" />
    </receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you do not have a receiver for your `PendingIntent`.

You might want to call `PendingIntent.getActivity()` instead of `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` to launch `StockActivity`.

From the documentation of `PendingIntent.getActivity()`:

> Retrieve a `PendingIntent` that will start a new activity, like calling
>   `Context.startActivity(Intent)`. Note that the activity will be started
>   outside of the context of an existing activity, so you must use the
>   `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` launch flag in the `Intent`.